# Regex to convert string number to currency

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string filed which holding the dollar amount. What I want to do is process the string and covert in actual currency.

Example:

Possible incoming string;

```
80
1000.00
1000.0
-100
```

Desired Outputs are;

```
100.00
1,000.00 
-100.00
```

How can I format the string with regex and covert it to the output I want?

Comment: How come "80 1000.00" changed into "100.00"?

Comment: What happened to the `80`?

Comment: Isn't there a currency formatter in C# ?

Comment: there is a C# formatter for this you know

Comment: You want a regex to solve this problem? Now you have two problems :) http://xkcd.com/1171/

Comment: If you really looking for using regex to perform that conversion you may want to check if question fits on http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help, otherwise it is not clear what you are looking for.

Comment: [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really clear what you mean by *actual currency*, but I'm assuming you just want a string that looks like the samples you've posted. Keep in mind that the `decimal` type (the type best suited to represent currency) doesn't have any actual formatting information.

You'll have to parse the `string` using `decimal.Parse`, then convert the value *back* to a `string` to get it into the desired format.

For example:

```
public string Format(string input)
{
    decimal value = decimal.Parse(input);

    return value.ToString("#,#.00");
}

// usage: Format("1000.0")
```

**Example:** https://dotnetfiddle.net/P7psPC

However if you're dealing with currency you can just use the `C` format specifier:

```
value.ToString("C");
```

This would output the following for your sample inputs:

```
$80.00
$1,000.00
$1,000.00
($100.00)
```

Comment: Yes correct I want the output looks like the sample I gave above. But what about the .00 at the end what if string comes 189.6 would that code convert this to 189.60 and string also might be negative and I want this to look like -189.60

Comment: @Ramsey K: Yes, those requirements are met with the function I posted. I added an example you can play with.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker I clarified your `ToString()` in my answer, but tried to not repeat or overstep your question.  Good answer.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a real currency converter in Microsoft .Net Framework, so you have to work within the constraints provided, which is `decimal`.  The closest you can get to your `decimal` being defaulted to *money* would be:

```
decimal amount = 0.00m
```

The `m` at the end is declaring that this decimal will represent money.  Which when added will provide basic rounding as if it were money.

However the easiest approach would be how Andrew Whitaker did the conversion.  The only thing I would add, is that when you utilize:

```
value.ToString("#,##0.00"); // Output: 0.96
value.ToString("#,#.00");   // Output .96
value.ToString("0.##");     // Output 0.6
```

To clarify the conversion with `ToString();` for the decimal.

Comment: Thanks Greg I will keep these in mind. Appreciated

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker, Hi Andrew hope you don't mind me asking another question. How can I add/insert double quote at the beginning and end of the string. Such as -1,000.00 I want this to look like "-1,000.00"  Thanks

Comment: I'm not Andrew, but the easiest way would be concatenation: `string content = @"/"" + Format(value) + @"/"";`  That would be the easiest, you'll need to use the `/` to escape it.

Comment: Thank you :) Is this going to look something like that?
I need to convert this to inline C# code
:
public string AddQuote(string input)
{
string content = @"/"" + Format(input) + @"/"";
return content;
}